# D programming language IRC library

Tags: d, irc

Hey, I'm searching for a D IRC library. Yes I know there is [dirclib](http://www.dprogramming.com/dirclib.php), but this one unfortunately doesn't seem to be compatible with version 1 or 2 of the language (anymore). When I try to use it with the 2.014 alpha for Ubuntu it throws several errors.

Do you've got any ideas/advises?

Answer (score 4):

As a general statement, D2 is bleeding edge and therefore library support for it is very poor.  Most libraries out there work with D1 and maybe have versions in testing for D2.  If you want to use D for something that requires complex infrastructure like libraries and tools, I'd stick with D1 for now because the language spec has been reasonably stable for a while.  dirclib apparently is a D1 lib, since it works with Tango, which is not ported to D2 yet.  If you can try the latest D1 compiler (1.040) and be more specific about what doesn't work, I might be able to provide more advice.

Also, if you're going to use D2, the downloads page is way out of date.  The latest version is 2.025, not 2.014, and can be found at ftp://ftp.digitalmars.com/.

Comment: Yes I already noticed that I'm using an old version, thanks.

I did as you told me to and downloaded and configured D1 with dirclib. Additionally I downloaded splat to run the example on the homepage.

http://paste.pocoo.org/show/WZYiqt3R37cCHRS2pMHh/ I'm getting these errors now.

Comment: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/GV3mnQzuyLvC4W9x2zjQ/ That's my dmd.conf. I unpacked the dirclib packet accordingly to the instructions given on the dirclib homepage. Seems like there's something wrong with the libraries.

Comment: Looks like a linker error, as opposed to a compiler error.  Make sure you've put the .lib or .a or whatever file for dirclib in some subdirectory of dmd/import.  The linker has to know where to look for the binaries.

Comment: I put those in the lib lib directory - I'm under Linux, that's surely the problem, right? That's why I already tried to recompile the libs according to the make.bat included in the dirclib file but it didn't work.

http://paste.pocoo.org/show/0myPpPXvpkdnSg59Bdut/

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, the lib files belong in dmd/lib, but I'm out of ideas, as the problem looks to be specific to dirclib's build process.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work under Windows aswell, seems like the lib is broken or I'm simply too stupid.